# Find list by content and not order

Tags: elixir

I have a lists of lists and one more list.

```
lists = [[3, 9, 1], [3, 9, 5], [4, 2], [8, 11], [9, 3, 5]]
source = [3, 5, 9]
```

How can I find all sub-lists in `lists` which contain all the elements of `source` regardless their order? There're 2 of such sub-lists in `lists`: [3, 9, 5] and [9, 3, 5].

Answer (score 2):

Quick look at list methods brought me here.

```
lists = [[3, 9, 1], [3, 9, 5], [4, 2], [9, 3, 5]]
s = [9,3,5]
Enum.filter(lists, fn x -> Enum.sort(x) == Enum.sort(s) end)
# =>[[3, 9, 5], [9, 3, 5]]
```

**UPDATE:**
You can also sort `s` and assign it to a variable,

```
t = Enum.sort(s)
```

then check the equivalence.

```
Enum.filter(lists, fn x -> Enum.sort(x) == t end)
```

which I believe will be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of [`Enum.member`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#member?/2) and [`Enum.all`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#all?/2) to filter the list:

```
lists |> Enum.filter(fn x ->
    Enum.all?(source, fn y -> Enum.member?(x, y) end)
end)
```